# How to send MediaStream AUDIO data with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, mediastream

I have been having trouble taking audio data that is being recorded from a mic and sending it to the other clients in the room so that people can speak to each other in real time. I have a method of doing this, but it is inefficient and choppy...

```js
setInterval(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(stream => {
      const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      mediaRecorder.start();
      const audioChunks = [];
      mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", (event) => {
        audioChunks.push(event.data);
      });

      mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
        socket.emit('liveAudioToServer', audioChunks)
      });

      setTimeout(() => {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
      },2000);
    });
  }, 2000);
```

This snippet records audio and sends a buffer every two seconds so that the client side compiles it and plays it upon receiving the data. I know there's got to be another way to do this. I tried a different method, but just receive an error.

```js
  socket.on('active', () => {
    if(navigator.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.getUserMedia(
        {audio: true}, 
        function(stream) {
          const audioContext3 = new AudioContext();
          const audioSource3 = audioContext3.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
          const analyser3 = audioContext3.createAnalyser();
          audioSource3.connect(analyser3);
          analyser3.fftSize = 256;
          const bufferLength = analyser3.frequencyBinCount;
          const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
          function sendAudioChunks(){
              analyser3.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);
              requestAnimationFrame(sendAudioChunks);
              socket.emit('liveAudioToServer', dataArray)
          }
          sendAudioChunks();
        },
        function(){ console.log("Error 003.")}
      );
    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is using webrtc an option for you? That is more suited for real time media stuff and is also pretty straightforward to use with a library like simple-peer for example. See https://github.com/feross/simple-peer

You can use websocket for the signalling aspect of webrtc and then use the simple-peer object to handle streaming itself once peers are connected.